# Eclipse build "current project" works from menu but not with shortcut

Tags: eclipse, build, shortcut

I have assigned CTRL-F7 to "Build all", which works fine. However, since my project consists of subprojects, I don't want to compile everything while I'm working on a library part, as the dependent projects will fail anyway.

I assigned also a shortcut F7 to "Build Project", but that doesn't do anything. When I use the menu "Project -> Build project" it builds the part I'm working on. I can also see in the menu that my shortcut is assigned, because it is shown there, but it doesn't trigger when I press it.

Is this a bug in Eclipse (Juno 4.3.0) or am I missing here something?

In the shortcut editor the "Where" clause is set to "In Windows", the same as the "Build All" shortcut. I also tried to set it to C++ Editor and others, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still in Eclipse Indigo, and I have assigned F7 to Build Project. It works.
There is maybe a regression because I found this bug :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383497

Read the bug to see if you find a solution. Try maybe to clean one time eclipse.
Start it with eclipse -clean or add it in your shortcut (don't forget to remove the parameter after, because the init is very slow).
If it does not work and your sources are under source control, create a temporary workspace, copy a bunch of project there and try again. Sometimes my workspace is corrupted but it is rare.

One solution if you have to many project to compile and they don't change too often, is too create jars, point to the jar and close the project.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This describes indeed the problem, but I don't really want to mess with eclipse right now. Sounds complicated to apply the patch and I already get sidetracked to much. :) Currently I close the other projects when I have more work on a sub part of the project, which has the same effect. Guess I have to wait for an update.